# SYN-ACK forwarding

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, packet-sniffers, spoofing

I have a server (A) that makes http requests to another http server (B). The header of the my request is altered to include a spoofed origin IP address, but due to the SYN-ACK response never getting back to my server, the connection to server B will never take place.

However, if I have software legitimately installed on the client machine that owns the actual IP address in the above request…

Q1) Would it be possible to forward the SYN-ACK packet (and sequence number) received from server B to my server A to complete the connection?

Q2) Could I use a sniffer like scapy on the client machine to do this or is this way more complex?

Remember, all I'm after is a response status code of "200" from server B getting to my server A.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is very similar to mitmproxy.
Have a look at their doc page, where they explain this extensively:
https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-howmitmproxyworks/